# In minidriver, is the value of hSCardCtx and hScard in PCARD_DATA can be changed after called CardAcquireContext?

Tags: cryptography, smartcard, cng

I am working on a project related **minidriver** to perform operations in smart card.

I have register smartcard in registry with proper ATR and minidriver information.
Now I am trying to generate keypair using ***CNG -> minidriver -> smart card***.

To achieve this I have called **NcryptOpenStorageProvider** from test application which returns success.

Now when I call **NCryptCreatePersistedKey** and **NCryptFinalizeKey** it can't communicate with smartcard.

In minidriver it calls "**CardAuthenticateEX**" and fails in **SCardTransmit**, though the previous commands for finding path and searching objects like **CardGetProperty, CardReadFile** can communicate with smart card successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the value of `hSCardCtx` or `hScard` fields of `CARD_DATA` can change after `CardAcquireContext` is called. So one should never store these handles to use them in subsequent functions calls but rather each minidriver function should retrieve these handles from its `PCARD_DATA` parameter. Failing to do so will cause issues like the one you are describing.